# (Beginner) Chatter action to publish an external image to a feed

Tags: chatter, canvas, chatter-feed

I'm a beginner to the Salesforce platform and I'm currently integrating my app with the Salesforce Chatter.

I want to create a `Chatter Action` that does the following:

- shows user an input or select box where user can type/select some value;
- creates a Chatter feed item with the externally loaded image (src of image is dynamically calculated based on the value typed into the input/select field).

I've searched a lot, and it seems that I can build a `Canvas App` and install it as a `Chatter Publisher Action`. Is that correct, and is it a way to achieve this task? Can anyone guide me to some (simple) code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities depending on where your Text box and Action needs to happen

**1.Assuming your requirement is not to mashup with SFDC UI**

Lets say your app is hosted else where and you do not want to bring your page into SFDC ,you can use salesforce REST API to accomplish your requirement .

Platform provides [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/) to push feed into SFDC provided you have set up your app to oauth with SFDC (Via Connected App)

**2.Canvas App - If you are trying to mashup your app inside SFDC (UI mash up)**

If you want to bring your webpage or app inside SFDC then canvas is tool for it .You will create a connected app and decode SFDC signed request and make an API callout to SFDC once signed request is validated .

There are sample apps in the docs [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/canvas_framework.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. "If you are trying to mashup your app inside SFDC (UI mash up)" - this is the way. Any Canvas app samples/links, please?

Comment: Added the docs link .Also which technology you are building the canvas app in ?

Comment: this will probably be a web stack (JavaScript/HTML/CSS) - is it a way to go?

Comment: Yes canvas is the way to go  here